# Getting the error: Undefined offset

Tags: php

I am writing a code for indexing the words for my search engine. Something like:

```
$handle = fopen("http://localhost/ps-friend/index.php", "r");   


while( $buf = fgets($handle,1024) )
{
   /* Remove whitespace from beginning and end of string: */
   $buf = trim($buf);

   /* Try to remove all HTML-tags: */
   $buf = strip_tags($buf);
   $buf = preg_replace('/&\w;/', '', $buf);

   /* Extract all words matching the regexp from the current line: */
   preg_match_all("/(\b[\w+]+\b)/",$buf,$words);

   /* Loop through all words/occurrences and insert them into the database(Not shown here): */
   for( $i = 0; $words[$i]; $i++ )
   {
     for( $j = 0; $words[$i][$j]; $j++ )
     {

       $cur_word = addslashes( strtolower($words[$i][$j]) );

        echo $cur_word;
       }
   }
}
```

When I echo `$cur_word` Why I keep getting the Error `Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\ps-friend\search.php on line 26` and sometimes on `line 24`. what is the way to correct it?

Comment: you simply assume the regex matched something, and loop on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for( $i = 0; $i < count($words); $i++ )
{
  for( $j = 0; $j < count($words[$i]); $j++ )
```

Your code is testing `$words[$i]` directly. But that means that the loop ends when it gets to an element that doesn't exist, which causes a warning because you try to reference it.

Your structure would be OK if you did:

```
for( $i = 0; isset($words[$i]); $i++ )
{
  for( $j = 0; isset($words[$i][$j]); $j++ )
```

`isset()` tests whether a variable exists, and doesn't warn.

Comment: Yeh, that was a mistake.. I corrected that. But still it gives the same error.

Comment: Solved :) thanks a lot.. will mark your answer as soon as this time limit is done ;)

Answer (score 4):

you for-loop looks a little bit strange. I think what you want is:

```
 for( $i = 0; $i < count($words); $i++ )
   {
```

Comment: I orrected it. But still its giving the same error :(

Comment: you corrected it for the second loop, too?